# Identifications of the space $A^* (G \times _H M) $

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a lie group, and let H be lie subgroup of G acting on G by right translation.
Let M be a H-manifold.

Why do these equalities hold:

For the algebra $ A^* (G \times _H M)$, we have:

$ A^* (G \times _H M) = A^* (G \times M)_{H-basic} = {C^\infty (G, [\wedge \mathfrak{g}^*  \otimes A^*(M)]_{H-hor})}^H$

Thank you for your help !

Comment: What does $A^*$ mean?

Comment: @Tobiaz Diez, if M is a manifold, we denote by $A^*(M)$ the algebra of differential forms on M.